# Adding to JSON array in JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have data being pulled in from various sources, each returning some form of JSON or similar, although, differently formatted each time.  I need to get them all into one array, but I can't figure out how to do it.

The first set is an array like this:

```
[
 Object {id="70", type="ab", dateadded="12345678"},
 Object {id="85", type="ab", dateadded="87654321"}, ... more items ...
]
```

The second set is being pulled in from Facebook, and is like this:

```
[
 Object {id="12341234234", created_time="12345678"},
 Object {id="567856785678", created_time="87654321"}, ... more items ...
]
```

So, I need to alter the second set so that it has 'type', and it has 'dateadded' instead of 'created_time', and then I need to get this all into one array so it can be sorted on 'dateadded'.

How can I do this?

Comment: This is no valid JSON String, is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have actual valid JSON instead of what you quoted above:

```
var jsonOld = '[{"id":"70","type":"ab","dateadded":"12345678"},{"id":"85","type":"ab","dateadded":"87654321"}]',
    jsonNew = '[{"id":"12341234234","created_time":"12345678"},{"id":"567856785678","created_time":"87654321"}]';
```

Then first parse these values into actual Javascript arrays:

```
var mainArr = JSON.parse(jsonOld),
    newArr = JSON.parse(jsonNew);
```

(If you already have actual Javascript arrays instead of JSON strings then skip the above step.)

Then just iterate over `newArr` and change the properties you need changed:

```
for (var i = 0, il = newArr.length; i < il; i++) {
    newArr[i].type = 'ab';
    newArr[i].dateadded = newArr[i].created_time;
    delete newArr[i].created_time;
}
```

And concatenate `newArr` into `mainArr`:

```
mainArr = mainArr.concat(newArr);
```

And sort on dateadded:

```
mainArr.sort(function(a, b) { return a.dateadded - b.dateadded; });
```

This will result in:

```
[{"id":"70","type":"ab","dateadded":"12345678"},
 {"id":"12341234234","type":"ab","dateadded":"12345678"},
 {"id":"85","type":"ab","dateadded":"87654321"},
 {"id":"567856785678","type":"ab","dateadded":"87654321"}]
```

[**See example**](http://jsfiddle.net/4YbYG/1/)

Comment: Thanks!  Yeah, I mangled what I have above, but the data is in the form you described, so this should work.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Use the first array's push() method:

```
// for each item in second array
    firstArray.push(convert(item));

function convert(obj) {
    // Convert obj into format compatible with first array and return it
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 Quicker, more concise solution to my problem. Brevity FTW!